# Обработка ctrl+click

Tags: jquery, javascript

В общем нужна функция, обязательно кроссбраузерная, выполняющая следующее:

- Левый click {действие 1}
- ctrl+левый клик {действие 2}

Может у кого есть готовое решение? Сам написал, но долбаный IE как всегда портит картину, т.е. ему вообще пофиг нажимаешь клавишу или нет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой стенд: абзац и кнопка. при простом нажатии на кнопку скрывается абзац, при клике по кнопке при нажатом <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - абзац не скрывается, но добавляется рамка (то есть отменяем обычное действие). Итак код:

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(event){
      $('p').animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 2000);
      if(event.ctrlKey == true){//если при щелчке нажата клавиша ctrl
        $('p').stop(true); //останавливаем анимацию и очищаем очередь 
        $('p').queue('fx', function(){
               $(this).css('border', '3px solid green'); //добавляем в очередь новое действие
               $(this).dequeue('fx'); //удаляем наше действие из очереди
             });
        }
  });
});
```

вот и всё)

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать!